# strange error when we create sub site using custom template "Template incorrect "

Tags: sharepoint-server

This web template requires that certain features be installed, activated, and licensed. The following problems are blocking application of the template:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You enable the feature according to feature ID by PowerShell command “Enable-SPFeature”. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Enable-SPFeature.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/enable-spfeature?view=sharepoint-ps)